# How can I select soft credit fields when exporting contributions?

Tags: contributions, export, search-builder, 4.6.6

We just upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.6 (under Joomla! 3.4.4, PHP Version 5.4.44,  MySQL 5.6.23) from CiviCRM 4.5.2.

The fields **Soft Credit For** and **Soft Credit Amount** no longer appear in the drop-down list when I choose "Select fields to export" as an option for exporting contributions.  They also disappeared from my saved field mappings, and no longer appear in Search Builder.

Unless I select "Contributions Only" in my search, I see data in these fields.  The fields are exported if I use the "Export PRIMARY fields" option, but that means I have to export a lot of fields I don't want and can't export any custom fields in the same .csv file.

Is this an intentional omission or will these fields be added back to the field selection drop-down for contributions in a subsequent release?

Thanks.